# Devise authentication via REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise in a Rails 3 app for authentication.

I have another app that updates records in a table via the REST interface.  Currently, I can't have `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in that table's controller.

Is there a way to supply a username, password via the REST interface? Or some other method to get the REST input authenticated?

Comment: I'm not on the computer but you want to look for the devise token authentication gem. You can use it to pass a secure token rather than the password and this way you stay secure.

Comment: Is this the one? lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

Comment: There's also this one https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication take your pick

Comment: OK - thanks - turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use token authentication to send params to the Rest API securely using either https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication or https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth